# Can I change the pressure amount of a brush line –drawn by mouse pen- after I drew it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, brush, pen-tool, stroke

I am using Illustrator for doing some calligraphy, and I am not really experienced with this program.

I am using a mouse pen with pressure to draw/write calligraphy. My question is: **Can I change the pressure amount after I drew lines using brush tool?**

Let’s say I drew a line, it is good but still not satisfactory. I just want to do a little change in pressure amount in some segments –not all the line- on line. Does Illustrator give me this option?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Width Tool` to adjust the thickness of a stroke (and some brushes) on a path:

[image: Width Tool]

Comment: thanks you very much John for the response. But you can not apply the width tool to the path you have made by pen pressure. Do you think there is a way to change that pressure effesct?

Comment: @user9379, correct, the width tool is for strokes, not brushes. You could remove the brush from the path and apply a stroke then edit the width. I'm unsure if there is a way to edit a brush in the way you're hoping for, and I don't have my tablet in front of me to mess with it unfortunately

Comment: Some brushes work with the width tool.... not all of them though. Calligraphic brushes will.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I know to do this is via DrawScribe, a plug in from [www.astutegraphics.com](http://astutegraphics.com/products/drawscribe/).

While you can use the Width Tool within Illustrator to manually adjust, add, or remove, width markers you have to do this on a one-at-a-time basis which can chew up time. Drawscribe allows you to draw path, then alter it's setting via commands after it's drawn. I'd encourage you to download the demo and try it. It's not a free plug in, but it's definitely worth the cost in my opinion.

Comment: Unfortunately The drawscrible is splitted into two individual plug-ins, which one can I go for it to try it?

Comment: Actually DrawScribe was discontinued. DynamicSketch is the new version which is more for dynamic width variables based upon stylus input. I would lean towards that plug in if you want variation *while you draw*. WidthScribe is good, but more for adjustment *after* you draw.